# How to define (sentence) units as lines in quanteda?

Tags: r, quanteda

I wonder if you can change the formation of sentences. Instead of punctuation to form the sentence, I would like a new row/ new line forming the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very minimal question, so I'm going to have to guess here what you intend, but I'm guessing that you want to segment your documents into lines, rather than sentences.  There are two ways to do this: to have a new corpus where each sentence is a document, or a new tokens object where each "token" is a line.

Getting both is a matter of using the `*_segment()` functions.  Here's two ways, with some sample text I will create where each line is a "sentence".

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.0.0

txt <- c(
  d1 = "Sentence one.\nSentence two is on this line.\nLine three",
  d2 = "This is a single sentence."
)
cat(txt)
## Sentence one.
## Sentence two is on this line.
## Line three This is a single sentence.
```

To make this into tokens, we use `char_segment()` with a newline being the segmentation pattern, and then coerce this into a list and then into tokens:

```r
# as tokens
char_segment(txt, pattern = "\n", remove_pattern = FALSE) %>%
  as.list() %>%
  as.tokens()
## Tokens consisting of 4 documents.
## d1.1 :
## [1] "Sentence one."
## 
## d1.2 :
## [1] "Sentence two is on this line."
## 
## d1.3 :
## [1] "Line three"
## 
## d2.1 :
## [1] "This is a single sentence."
```

If you want to make each of the lines into a "document" that can be segmented further, then use `corpus_segment()` after constructing a corpus from the `txt` object:

```r
# as documents
corpus(txt) %>%
  corpus_segment(pattern = "\n", extract_pattern = FALSE)
## Corpus consisting of 4 documents.
## d1.1 :
## "Sentence one."
## 
## d1.2 :
## "Sentence two is on this line."
## 
## d1.3 :
## "Line three"
## 
## d2.1 :
## "This is a single sentence."
```